# Why won't this SQL statement run

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

```
SELECT * FROM agency
INNER JOIN TUser
[agency].[dbo].[Matrix_Branch_ID]=[TUser].[dbo].[client_id]
Microsoft SQL Server Managment Studio gives me:
```

SQL Server Management Studio gives me:

> Msg 170, Level 15, State 1, Line 3 
>   Line 3: Incorrect syntax near '.'.

**Edit**

After fixing the syntax errors with

```
SELECT * FROM agency
INNER JOIN TUser
ON dbo.agency.Matrix_Branch_ID=dbo.TUser.client_id
```

SQL Server Management Studio now gives me:

> Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid object name 'agency'.
>   Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid object name 'TUser'.

Comment: why is agency and Tuser BEFORE the dbo?

Comment: If you're running this in SSMS - are you in the **right** database; the one that contains those two tables?

Comment: @marc_s you're right. How do you tell/specify the database your querying in Microsoft Management studio because in the object explorer I expanded the right table in the right database. Since your answer fixed the problem if you post it I'll accept it as the right one

Comment: In the top left hand corner youll see a dropdown that more than likely has "master", just change that to your current DB.  
OR
You can do SELECT * from DBNAME.dbo.TABLENAME
Either way works

Comment: @Celeritas please don't dramatically change the substance of your question like that. It confusing for future visitors. It's better to simply ask a new question. Since you've gotten an answer to fix your secondary problem, I've combined the two revisions. For more see [What is the etiquette for changing the substance of a question?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/48345/)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're running this in SSMS - are you in the right database; the one that contains those two tables?

[image]

You can see that current database you're in when a query window is active - both in a drop-down on the toolbar, as well as the query window's footer.

Answer (score 5):

You're missing the `ON` keyword See the `<joined table>` grammar in [FROM (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177634.aspx)

> ```
> <joined_table> ::=  {
>    <table_source> <join_type> <table_source> ON <search_condition> 
>    | <table_source> CROSS JOIN <table_source> 
>    | left_table_source { CROSS | OUTER } APPLY right_table_source 
>    | [ ( ] <joined_table> [ ) ]  }
> ```

Also the `[dbo]` between what I presume is the table and fields names is wrong. See [Using Identifiers As Object Names](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187879%28SQL.105%29.aspx)

this should work

```
SELECT * FROM agency
INNER JOIN TUser
ON [agency].[Matrix_Branch_ID]=[TUser].[client_id]
```

Comment: I'm getting a new error (see original post please). I also tried it with your exact syntax and same error.

Comment: Is there a table called TUser? do you need to write dbo.TUser for the table name?

Comment: @Celeritas do you get results from `SELECT SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id) , name  from sys.objects where name IN ('agency', 'TUser')`

Comment: @ConradFrix No, to answer your question. The problem was I wasn't connected to a database.

Comment: @KrisGruttemeyer the OP changed his question dramatically after my answer. Here's the [original question](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/11143016/1)

Answer (score 2):

Are you selecting the correct database? SQL Server defaults to using the master database, which is not the one you probably want.

You probably want to qualify the schema on the table, not on the items you are selecting. For instance:

```
Use [Database_name]

SELECT * FROM dbo.agency
INNER JOIN dbo.TUser ON agency.Matrix_Branch_ID=TUser.client_id
```